# f# does it need linear time to get last element of an array

Tags: arrays, f#

For arbitrary n, accessing the last element of

```
[|1 .. n|]
```

will take linear time (as a function of n).

Is it true or false ?

Comment: False. F# arrays are usual .NET arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False. F# arrays are usual .NET arrays.
["The type of all F# arrays is the .NET Framework type Array. Therefore, F# arrays support all the functionality available in Array."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx)

Comment: Also see: [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx) `The running time of an array access is denoted O(1) because it is constant. That is, regardless of how many elements are stored in the array, it takes the same amount of time to lookup an element. This constant running time is possible solely because an array's elements are stored contiguously, hence a lookup only requires knowledge of the array's starting location in memory, the size of each array element, and the element to be indexed.`